# @npm runnig in Vue.js error througs node scripts and node bins

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

When I was trying to serve my Vue Project by using command

> npm run serve

It gives me error mentioned as below

> > vue-heroes@0.1.0 serve /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes
> > vue-cli-service serve

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! vue-heroes@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-heroes@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/numan/.npm/_logs/2021-10-08T10_47_52_241Z-debug.log
numan@numan-khan:~/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes$ npm i

> yorkie@2.0.0 install /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/yorkie
> node bin/install.js

setting up Git hooks
can't find .git directory, skipping Git hooks installation

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /home/numan/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:

> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/numan/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1324 packages from 972 contributors and audited 1393 packages in 46.741s

12 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 104 vulnerabilities (1 low, 43 moderate, 60 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
numan@numan-khan:~/Desktop/vue-getting-started/07-accessing-data/begin/vue-heroes$ npm audit fixnpm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 65 packages from 52 contributors, removed 12 packages and updated 32 packages in 140.847s

52 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

fixed 20 of 104 vulnerabilities in 1393 scanned packages
66 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
4 package updates for 18 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
(use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)

Idont khow how to fix it mnually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because because my Project was built. Then I update my npm simply

**npm i -g npm**

Then I develop my project by using command

**npm run dev**

This will solve the error